# Cakephp Upload Plugin - Saving Custom Path in DIR Field

Tags: cakephp, upload, cakephp-2.0

I am using the https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload

`'pathMethod' => 'primaryKey'.`

And the below path

`'path' => '{ROOT}webroot{DS}files{DS}upload{DS}{model}{DS}{field}{DS}',`

So, I am stuck at a point where in I want to save the DIR with a more elaborate information than just the primaryKey ID in DIR field
eg DIR field to be saved as "upload/organization/logo/1", currently its just saves "1"

I have gone though the documentation several times, but unable to understand about how to solve the above situation. Please help through  with this.

Why want this feature, when everything is happening auto-magically, using only dir field in the view helps a lot, to link the file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With the current code base, I believe the only solution you have at your disposal is to use the pathMethod of 'flat', use the 'handleUploadedFileCallback' property and manage the handling of directory creation and file movement (from TMP to 'path') on your own...and then also save the 'dir' property of your model (if you're saving that) within that callback (or afterSave) as well. Using 'pathMethod' => 'flat' removes the automatic saving of the file's location.

According to GitHub tickets, it seems that Jose might have plans to implement this feature in the future, but it's a "WIP" (Work in Progress).